# Im not able to save the standard object account using Extensions by over-riding the SAVE method

Tags: visualforce

**Im not able to save the standard object account  using Extensions by over-riding the SAVE method 
Help me out guys 

Thnks in advance**

**I'm getting this Error :**

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Account Name]: [Account Name]
Error is in expression '{!savenow}' in component  in page samplepage: Class.sampleExtension.savenow: line 19, column 1

Class.sampleExtension.savenow: line 19, column 1

**Extension ::**

```
public with sharing class sampleExtension { 

public String Type{get;set;}
public String Name{get;set;}
public String Region{get;set;}
public account acc = new account();

public sampleExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}

    public PageReference savenow() {

    acc.Name = Name;

    acc.Type= Type;
    acc.Region__c= Region;
system.debug('name'  + acc.name + 'Type'  + acc.Type + 'Region'  + acc.Region__c  );
    insert acc;

    System.debug('nickName: '+Type);

    return null;
}

}
```

**VF Page ::**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="sampleExtension" >    
    <p/>
<apex:form >

    <apex:inputField value="{!account.Name}"/> <p/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!account.Type}"/> <p/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!account.Region__c}"/> <p/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savenow}"/>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: let me guess: you don't set any `Name` to your account?

Comment: There's no issue with your override of the Save button - you aren't supplying a Name on the Account record. Set required="true" on your first input field and this problem should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no need to create separate variables for assigning values to new record i.e. Name, Type, Region etc if you are using inputfield on vf page.

Initiate "account" variable in constructor and declare that as getter/setter.
Hope this works.